# ignoring rows where a column has non-numeric characters in its value

Tags: sql, presto, amazon-athena

I have a table with a column that has some variable data. I would like to select only the rows that have values with numerical characters `[0-9]`

The column would look someting like this:

```
time
1545123
none
1565543
1903-294
```

I would want the rows with the first and third values only (1545123 and 1565543). None of my approaches have worked.

I've tried:

```
WHERE time NOT LIKE '%[^0-9]+%'
WHERE NOT regexp_like(time, '%[^0-9]+%')
WHERE regexp_like(time, '[0-9]+')
```

I've also tried these expressions in a CASE statement, but that was also a no go. Am I missing something here?

This is on Amazon Athena, which uses an older version of Presto

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can use regexp matching only numbers like `'^[0-9]+$'` or `'^\d+$'`:

```sql
-- sample data
WITH dataset (time) AS (
    VALUES  
                        ('1545123'),
                ('none'),
                ('1565543'),
                ('1903-294')
) 

--query
select *
from dataset
WHERE regexp_like(time, '^[0-9]+$')
```

Output:

| time |
| --- |
| 1545123 |
| 1565543 |

Another option which I would say should not be used in this case but can be helpful in some others is using `try` with `cast`:

```sql
--query
select *
from (
        select try(cast(time as INTEGER)) time
        from dataset
    )
where time is not null
```